# Expectation of the minimum of two $\mathcal U(0, 1)$ r.v.'s conditional on it being greater than or equal to some value

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

> Let $X_1, X_2$ be i.i.d. $\mathcal U(0, 1)$ (continuous) r.v.'s, and let $0 \le R \le 1$ be some number.  What is $\mathbb E[\min(X_1, X_2) \mid \min(X_1, X_2) \ge R]$?

**My attempt:**  Let $Y = \min(X_1, X_2)$.  Let $F$ be the CDF, and $f$ the pmf of $Y$.  We can see that
$$
\begin{align*}
F(y) &= 1 - (1 - y)^2 \\
f(y) &= \frac{\operatorname d F}{\operatorname d y} = 2(1 - y)\text{.}
\end{align*}
$$
Now I need to get $f(y \mid Y \ge R)$, but I'm a bit lost.  How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bayes' Rule is applicable (or just the definition of conditional probability):

$$f_{Y}(y\mid Y\geqslant R) ~=~ \dfrac{f_Y(y)~\mathbf 1_{y\geqslant R}}{1-F_Y(R)}$$